# How to achieve inner shadow in text objects in canvas?

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

I am struggling to achieve inner shadow for text objects in canvas / fabric js .
Can you please provide a way to get inner shadow in canvas.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VVs5.png)

Comment: Try something & ask for help when you are blocked.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37378088/inset-shadow-on-html5-canvas-image/37380488#37380488